# What is better “createEmbeddedView” or “createComponent" to render dynamic widgets in angular 5 component. Also, avoid the memory leakages

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-directives

There is one scenario in my project need to add dynamic widgets to the angular component but I get confused between “createEmbeddedView” and “createComponent” and what is the better way to implement this.?

**component.html** (This is component HTML file)

```
`<ng-template [ad-renderer]="renderMapper" ></ng-template>`
```

I have widgets service may be it returns widgets object( 20 or 30 widgets) and need to dynamically render these widgets in Angular 5 component html file (component.html) using a custom ad-renderer directive.

**renderer.ts** (this is directive)

```
widgets = { 
    "name":"Widget-1", "data":{},
    "name":"Widget-2", "data":{},
    "name":"Widget-3", "data":{},
    "name":"Widget-4", "data":{},
    "name":"Widget-5", "data":{},
    "name":"Widget-6", "data":{},
    "name":"Widget-7", "data":{},
    "name":"Widget-8", "data":{}
 }
```

Comment: what are these widgtets?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :), I got the Answer.

widgets is an object which comes from service refer this link( https://api.myjson.com/bins/1elnxj ).

Widgets only contain the data and these data need to map to the renderer(predefined component). Just I create multiple instances of the same component.

consider I have two widgets popular courses and enrolled courses respectively. Those widgets need to display into the carousel. So, I have created a carousel renderer( which is Angular 5 component ) and I create an instance of carousel renderer for every widget

Comment: so your issue is solved?

Comment: Yes , thanks.     :)